# Server 2003 List AD Objects in OU

Tags: windows, active-directory, groups

I need to list via command line objects within an OU. I know I can use "Export List" in the GUI, but I'd rather be able to do it via CLI as well. I can use a combination of `dsquery` piped into `dsget` for groups to get members,

```
# dsquery group -name "standardDistGroup"
"CN=standardDistGroup,OU=templateOU,DC=employees,DC=MyOrganization,DC=com"

# dsquery group -name "standardDistGroup"  | dsget group -members

"CN=John Doe,OU=templateOU,DC=employees,DC=MyOrganization,DC=com"
"CN=Otto Normalverbraucher,OU=templateOU,DC=employees,DC=MyOrganization,DC=com"
```

but the same syntax doesn't appear to work for getting OU container objects.

```
# dsquery OU -name "ByeBye"
"OU=ByeBye,DC=employees,DC=MyOrganization,DC=com"

# dsquery OU -name "ByeBye"  | dsget ou -members

dsget failed:`-members' is an unknown parameter.
type dsget /? for help.
# dsquery OU -name "ByeBye"  | dsget group -members
dsget failed:OU=ByeBye,DC=employees,DC=MyOrganization,DC=com:The object class of the target does not match the one specified on the command line.
type dsget /? for help.
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this via CLI? Powershell isn't available on this server.

Comment: I just want to make sure you know Powershell can be installed on Server 2003 and would probably be much simpler for you. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/03/how-to-install-powershell-on-windows-server-2003-and-enable-remote-powershell-managementall-servers-should-have-this-done/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups have members, OU's do not have members. OU's **contain** other objects.
You will need a slightly different command for each object type you want to list at a given path.

```
dsquery user OU=ByeBye,DC=employees,DC=MyOrganization,DC=com

dsquery computer OU=ByeBye,DC=employees,DC=MyOrganization,DC=com

dsquery ou OU=ByeBye,DC=employees,DC=MyOrganization,DC=com
```

Using powershell would be the better way to do this. You can query objects with `get-adobject`, `get-aduser`, `get-adcomputer` and also navigate AD like a filesystem with the `AD:` drive after you `import-module activeDirectory`.